# Javascript object factory instanceof

Tags: javascript, instanceof, objectfactory

Why does the following object factory pattern code return false...

```
var Animal = function(name) {
var temp = new Object();
    temp.name = name;
    return temp;
}

var animal = Animal("fox");

console.log(animal instanceof Animal);
```

...while the following constructor pattern code returns true;

```
var Animal = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var animal = new Animal("fox");

console.log(animal instanceof Animal);
```

Comment: Because `new Object` is a new instance of an `Object`, not an `Animal`.

Comment: Why would you have expected it to work otherwise? Factories are just ordinary functions. `JSON.parse("{}") instanceof JSON.parse` is `false` just as well.